# How do I enable TTL-Cache control on my site?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, performance, webpack, pagespeed

I tried google pageSpeed to check the possibilities to enhance the performance of my REACT site(create through CRA). The analytics show that I need to Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy. It shows list of files in which I can control the caching. How could I do that?

I tried to set the cache-control header with max-Age, It only works on the files that are served from the back-end. Since the images, css and JS are served from the build/static folder. I am unable to set a cache-control value.

Comment: something is also serving what's coming from your `build/static` folder. You need to configure whatever is serving your react app to use the necessary cache-control headers. For example, it could be nginx, apache, your app server, etc. you haven't given us enough information

Comment: @mistahenry Thanks for your comment. "You need to configure whatever is serving your react app to use the necessary cache-control headers." This gave me the answer. I configured them on the s3 Side and it works. Thanks!